# Make polygon of GeoJSON layer unclickable after first click in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, events

I have added a GeoJSON file consisting of multiple polygons to a leaflet map. Now after clicking on any of those polygons I don't want Leaflet to accept any subsequent click events for this specific polygon anymore. This is what I have tried to no avail:

```
leafletGeoJsonLayer.on('click', function (e) {
  ...color clicked polygon red or green...
  e.layer.options.interactive = false; //don't accept further click events for this polygon
}
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use some custom polygon/layer property, like for example `wasClicked` (name can be any, as long is does not conflict with standard Leaflet layer properties), to mark the fact that polygon/layer was already clicked. If `wasClicked` is `true`, further processing is skipped.

Code could then look something like this:

```
leafletGeoJsonLayer.on('click', function (e) {
  var layer = e.target;
  if (layer.wasClicked) return;

  layer.wasClicked = true;
  ...
}
```

Other possible solution would be to cancel layer `click` event processing with the `.off` method. In this case code could look something like this:

```
function processGeoJsonClick(e) {
  var layer = e.target;
  layer.off('click', processGeoJsonClick);
  ...
}

leafletGeoJsonLayer.on('click', processGeoJsonClick);
```

Answer (score 3):

I see (at least) four ways of achieving this, none of them being really clean:

---

The (default) `L.SVG` vector renderer applies the `interactive` option only when a vector is added to the renderer. Thus, removing and re-adding the polygon should do the trick.

```
leafletGeoJsonLayer.on('click', function (e) {
  e.layer.options.interactive = false;
  leafletGeoJsonLayer.removeLayer(e.layer).addLayer(e.layer);
}
```

---

The (non-default) `L.Canvas` renderer checks for the `interactive` option at every pointer interaction. Thus, telling your GeoJSON vectors to draw inside a `L.Canvas` should do the trick.

```
var canvasRenderer = L.canvas();
var leafletGeoJsonLayer = L.geoJson({ 
  style: function() { 
    return { renderer: canvasRenderer, /* etc */ };
  }
});
```

---

The (default) `L.SVG` vector renderer relies on an internal `addInteractiveTarget`/`removeInteractiveTarget` logic to dispatch leaflet-decorated events to the appropriate objects. It's possible to manually detach the SVG DOM node for the polygon for this logic, by reading the code of the `L.SVG` renderer regarding removing a vector layer and using an undocumented private property of vector layers:

```
leafletGeoJsonLayer.on('click', function (e) {
  e.layer.removeInteractiveTarget(e.layer._path);
}
```

The path will still dispatch pointer events, but they'll be detached from the Leaflet logic, and thus ignored by any event handlers set up for the `GeoJSON` group.

---

Assuming a SVG renderer, since paths are actually DOM nodes (and the target of the original DOM events), it's possible to update their CSS properties. For this problem specifically, [the `pointer-events` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) is of interest.

```
leafletGeoJsonLayer.on('click', function (e) {
  e.originalEvent.target.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
}
```

That should be equivalent to

```
leafletGeoJsonLayer.on('click', function (e) {
  e.layer._path.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
}
```